# How can I display these images with CSS instead of HTML?

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to add a some social icons to the siderbar of my blog. In my sidebar i have some topics organized in a list. At the end of this list I would like to have one list item that displays my social icons. 
I managed to achieve this by using the  tag and got something like this:

```
<!-- Social icons -->
<li>
<img src="/images/Twitter.png"><a href="http://twitter.com"></a></img>
<img src="/images/Github.png"><a href="http://github.com"></a></img>
<img src="/images/Quora.png"><a href="http://quora"></a></img>
<img src="/images/LinkedIn.png"><a href="http://linkedin.com"></a></img>
<img src="/images/Google.png"><a href="http://google.com"></a></img>
<img src="/images/Flickr.png"><a href="http://flickr.com"></a></img>
<img src="/images/Vimeo.png"><a href="http://vimeo.com"></a></img>
<img src="/images/YouTube.png"><a href="http://youtube.com"></a></img>
</li>
```

However, I don't like this approach because

- the links don't work for some reason
- I am not able to resize the images (they are way to big like this)
- I won't be able to have a hover effect

As I am just beginning with CSS I don't know how to solve this problem. I tried using some div containers and ids and classes but I couldn't get it working. So this is to all of you CSS experts:

How can I have resized images, displayed inline, with link and with hover effect using CSS and getting rid of those  tags?

Comment: The images need to be INSIDE your A-tags

Comment: `<img></div>` is pure nonsense anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Links do not work because the tags are incorrectly nested: `<a href="..."><img src="..." /></a>`.

To display the images using CSS, you would remove the `img` tag and add `background-image` CSS style to the `<a>` element (together with some padding etc. so that the text does not overlap). [Here is an step-by-step example](http://ran.ge/2009/11/11/css-trick-turning-a-background-image-into-a-clickable-link/).

Also some other reading material how to enhance such scenario: [CSS sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) (merge all these icons together in a single download to speed up) and [CSS Data URI](http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/) (embed the icons directly in .css file to reduce download count).

Answer (score 0):

You could use css background.

```
.class{
background-image:url('image.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your first example, format as follows:

```
<a href= "http://twitter.com">
<img src= "/images/Twitter.png" />
</a>
```

For the hover, if you assign your links to a class, you should be able to set the hover qualities as well.

http://kyleschaeffer.com/user-experience/pure-css-image-hover/

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is a good example for your question

For links use like this --

```
<a href="http://twitter.com"> <img src="/images/Twitter.png" /> </a>
<a href="http://github.com"> <img src="/images/Github.png" /> </a>
<a href="http://quora.com"> <img src="/images/Quora.png" /> </a>
```

For the hover effect use

```
li a:hover{color:#ff0000} as css
```

this will show red color on hover.